# Could you explain the Sad Bhuja form of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu?

Tags: symbolism

Could you explain the Sad Bhuja form of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu ?

Answer (score 2):

> The form of Sad-bhuja, the six-armed Lord Gaurasundara, is a
>   representation of three incarnations. The form of Sri Ramacandra is
>   symbolized by a bow in one hand and an arrow in another, the form of
>   Lord Sri Krsna is symbolized by a stick and a flute like those
>   generally held by a cowherd boy, and Lord Caitanya Mahäprabhu is
>   symbolized by a sannyasa-danda and a kamandalu, or waterpot.

<sup>Source : [Caitanya Caritamrta  Ādi 17.12](http://vedabase.com/en/cc/adi/17/12)</sup>